# Persisting BloomFilterRedis

Tags: java, redis, bitset, bloom-filter

We use BloomFilter in a pretty busy flow computing environment with about 50K operations per second. Earlier, the filters were implemented on a per node basis and would periodically be cleared, to prevent saturation.

With the current implementation based on `BloomFilterRedis`, it's been a bit of a challenge to keep the filter from saturation by persisting existing values and copying the BitSet over to a new instance, there is no provision to set the older BitSet into the new instance with a setter or a constructor.
Looking to hear from somebody with experience in this library

Comment: Did you try to use the server side Bloom Filter based on the Redis module RedisBloom? It should allow you to get much higher TP.

Comment: Will look at it, though I am curious how large a filter can I configure, eventually I have to clear this one too and my concern is for flows that happen in the meanwhile. I did ponder using in memory filter for the duration but the transition will again be messy

Comment: Not sure I got your requirements, but notice this module also supports Cuckoo Filter which also supports deletes from the filter.